Why doesn't it need undefined or null for optional parameters in Node.js?
See this example from Node.js docs:
response.writeHead(statusCode[, statusMessage][, headers])

const body = 'hello world';
response
  .writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body),
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
  })
  .end(body);   

The second parameter of writeHead function should be statusMessage.
Why can this second parameter be skipped automatically, don't we need a undefined or null for the parameter? How does Node.js know the object is for the third parameter?
Why not:
const body = 'hello world';
response
  .writeHead(200, undefined, {
    'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body),
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
  })
  .end(body); 


You could always take a look at the source code for writeHead to find out. That link may not age well!

The documentation says:

The last argument, headers, are the response headers. Optionally one can give a human-readable statusMessage as the second argument.

The implementation of the writeHead function checks whether the second argument is string or object and behaves accordingly. You can see it in the source.
if (typeof reason === 'string') {
  // writeHead(statusCode, reasonPhrase[, headers])
  // ...
} else {
  // writeHead(statusCode[, headers])
  // ...
}


Thanks, so all the Nodejs API functions support such logic if the parameters for the function are in different types?

In the code for the function it'll be looking at the type of the arguments and determine what to do
So something like
    const writeHead = (status, bodyOrHeaders, maybeHeaders) => {
      let body, headers;

      if (maybeHeaders) {
        // if we have a 3rd arg, we assume its the value for headers
        // and the body is the 2nd arg
        headers = maybeHeaders;
        body = bodyOrHeaders;
      } else {
        // otherwise we didnt get a 3rd arg so assume headers is 2nd
        body = null;
        headers = bodyOrHeaders;
      }

      // ... do something with status, body and headers
    }

